# Buttons below the Touchpad not working

Tags: xorg, touchpad, dell-latitude

On my Dell Latitude 4590, the two buttons below the Touchpad are not functional.

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0816:00 044E:120A Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0816:00 044E:120A Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]     <-- of interest
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL0816:00 044E:120A UNKNOWN             id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Its properties are :

```
$ xinput list-props 13
Device 'DELL0816:00 044E:120A Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (184):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (186): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (318): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (319):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (320):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (321):    11.672794
    Synaptics Edges (343):  47, 1152, 34, 601
    Synaptics Finger (344): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (345):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (346):   59
    Synaptics Tap Durations (347):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (348):   0
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (349):  75
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (350):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (351):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (352): -27, 27
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (353): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (354):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (355): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.147493, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (356):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (357):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (358):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (359): 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (360):   1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (361): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (362):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (363): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (364):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (365): 1
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (366):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (367): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (368):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (369): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (370):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (371):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (372):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (373): 12, 12
    Synaptics Area (374):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (375): 6, 6
    Device Product ID (311):    1102, 4618
    Device Node (310):  "/dev/input/event12"
```

The strange thing is that **no event** is generated when I click on the two buttons below the Touchpad which was checked using `xev`.

Comment: Run the Dell hardware diagnostics from a bootable USB key and see if this is a hardware problem (diagnostics) or software driver issue (no hardware issue).

Comment: seems to be available for Windows only.

Comment: Try Dell Support and see if they can supply a Linux driver. See if Bluetooth works and use a Bluetooth mouse (I do this). Get a LogiTech Mouse with an RF USB key.  Try these things.

Comment: So, you suggest that the _PixArt USB Optical Mouse_ actually connected may cause the problem ? unplug and hotplug does not resolve the problem, I will reboot without the plugged mouse.

Comment: I was suggesting an external Mouse. But if one is connected, yes, temporarily remove it , restart and test.

Comment: done, still not working. The problem seems to be related to the kernel module being used.

Comment: Try Dell Support for a better driver or see if Synaptics has a driver for your machine.